# SPFx - Office UI React - How to default select user in People Picker

Tags: sharepoint-server, feature-activation, spfx-webparts, office-ui-fabric-react

I want to set default selected Item on people picker?

```
<NormalPeoplePicker
        defaultSelectedItems={()}
        inputProps={{ disabled: true }}
        onChange={this._onChangePeoplePicker}
        onResolveSuggestions={this._onFilterChangedPeoplePicker}
        getTextFromItem={(persona: IPersonaProps) => persona.primaryText}
        pickerSuggestionsProps={suggestionProps}
        className={'ms-PeoplePicker'}
        key={'normal'} />
</div>
```

How to use defaultSelectedItems --> https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/peoplepicker ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found that earlier versions lacked the selected items property but the current version, 5.28.0, includes the selected items property and with that I was able to set the default select. I didn't have any luck getting the default selected items to work unless I had the value the first time the component was rendered. If I passed a default and then based off of SP REST calls changed the state the component would update. Here is an example of what I am now using that works.

```
<CompactPeoplePicker selectedItems={this.props.selectedItems} />
```